# Error when deploying SvelteKit to Vercel while npm run preview works fine locally

Tags: sass, svelte, vercel

I have a problem where I get the following error when deploying my SvelteKit website to Vercel:

```
> Using @sveltejs/adapter-auto
18:05:29.787    > 404 /about (linked from /)
18:05:29.787        at file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/chunks/index5.js:167:11
18:05:29.787        at visit (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/chunks/index5.js:326:5)
18:05:29.802    Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

The website works fine both in dev and build environment locally.

I have been trying all day to fix this and in the process broke my latest website version, which now gives a different error when using `npm run dev` locally:

```
6:29:51 PM [vite] Internal server error:  File to import not found or unreadable: ../scss/components/footer.
  Plugin: vite-plugin-svelte
  File: /Users/koenraijer/Documents/Code/Svelte/kaashuys/src/lib/footer/Footer.svelte
6:29:51 PM [vite] Internal server error:  File to import not found or unreadable: ../scss/components/nav.
  Plugin: vite-plugin-svelte
  File: /Users/koen/Documents/Code/Svelte/kaashuys/src/lib/header/Header.svelte
6:29:51 PM [vite] Internal server error:  File to import not found or unreadable: ../scss/components/footer.
  Plugin: vite-plugin-svelte
  File: /Users/koen/Documents/Code/Svelte/kaashuys/src/lib/footer/Footer.svelte
6:29:51 PM [vite] Internal server error:  File to import not found or unreadable: ../scss/components/nav.
  Plugin: vite-plugin-svelte
  File: /Users/koen/Documents/Code/Svelte/kaashuys/src/lib/header/Header.svelte
```

This exact same nav file was imported perfectly fine in the version used to generate the first error message. All of these files are present.

When running `npm run preview`, suddenly it *does* work.

First part of my `package-lock.json`:

```
{
  "name": "blog-template",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "lockfileVersion": 2,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "blog-template",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "dependencies": {
        "@fontsource/fira-mono": "^4.5.0",
        "@lukeed/uuid": "^2.0.0",
        "cookie": "^0.4.1",
        "scss": "^0.2.4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "next",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-static": "^1.0.0-next.26",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "next",
        "eslint": "^7.32.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-svelte3": "^3.2.1",
        "mdsvex": "^0.9.8",
        "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
        "postcss": "^8.4.5",
        "prettier": "^2.4.1",
        "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.4.0",
        "svelte": "^3.44.0",
        "svelte-dark-mode": "^2.0.0",
        "svelte-preprocess": "^4.10.1",
        "typescript": "^4.5.4"
      }
    },
```

Other things I've tried:

- run `npm audit`, update outdated packages etc.
- removed everything scss related, reinstalled svelte-preprocess.
- checked if removing the sveltePreprocess config `scss: prependData` line did anything.
- Incrementally added newer parts to the earlier version that did work, but I didn't find manage to find the perpetrator.

I don't know how I broke it or how to fix it...